# How to set the colors in the justgage based on different conditions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, justgage

I have Power Level Sensor.I want to set different colors based on the different conditions.The conditions are:

```
if (var1>var2):
    enable green color
elif(var1<var3):
    enable red color
elif(var3<var1<var2):
    enable orange color
```

I wrote the code for that:

```
var g1 = new JustGage({

          id: "g1",
          value:0,
          min: 0,
          max: 50000,
          label: "SSTR",
          title: "Ant-1 SSTR",
          customSectors : [{"lo":var2,"hi":var1,"color":"#3aa914"},
                   {"lo":var1,"hi":var3,"color":"#FF0000"},
                   {"lo":var3,"hi":var2,"color":"#FFA500"}],
         levelColorsGradient: false
});
```

and calling justgage function for every millisecond.The var1,var2 and var3 are the global variables.

```
setInterval((function () {
    g1.refresh(var1);
    }), 1000);
```

Is this is the right approach?
Can we pass more than one argument(like color,id) to justgage refresh function?

How can I set the different colors in the gustgage based on different conditions?

Comment: It looks like you can't do that: the `.refresh()` function of JustGage is extreme simplistic and only accepts two arguments: a value, and an optional max value. It looks like you just want different colors based on the value, right? You can just hardcode the color thresholds when initializing it: do you really need a "dynamic" color threshold?

Comment: Thanks@Terry,U mean that we can pass val and max value as arguments to refresh function .Yeah i want to use different colors based on the conditions.How can i hardcode ?can you explain clearly?I need dynamic color threshold.

Comment: I think JustGage already does that for you: let's say you want red from 0-50 and green from 51-100, you can do that using `customSectors: [{ lo: 0, hi: 50, color: 'red' }, { lo: 51, hi: 100, color: 'green' }]`, you don't need to pass in any variables. And unfortunately the plugin does not support updating the instances with anything else but value and maxValue, so if you want dynamic color thresholds (i.e. changing at which point the color changes dynamically), you will need to look for another solution.

Comment: Thank you Terry.I know this method.but i want  to use these global variables for low and high as they are changing every time.These are not constants.